# Generate key pair deterministically from a particular seed

Tags: rsa, key-derivation

I've been reading ["SQRL Secure QR Login" at Gibson's website](https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm), and I'm wondering if there is a way to generate an RSA private/public key-pair based on some cryptographically secure input, so that if the input stays the same we keep getting the same key pair on the output.

The linked web-site uses elliptic curve cryptography to achieve this property.  Is it not possible with RSA?

Comment: ecliptic $\mapsto$ elliptic $\:$ ? $\;\;\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's possible; all you need is take your cryptographically secure input, feed it as the key to a CSRNG, and then use the CSRNG output as the source of randomness to an RSA key generation algorithm.  For a concrete example, there are several such key generation methods in FIPS 186-3, with the cryptographically secure input being the 'seed' (and you would fix all the other various parameters).

This is easy; however this is not cheap.  RSA key generation involves testing various large numbers for primality; depending on the hardware you have (and the RSA key size you are attempting to build), this can take multiple seconds.  Depending on the your requirements, this can be a deal breaker.  In contrast, the key generation method for elliptic curves is cheap; that is undoubtedly why the guys on the web-site selected it.